# Disable context menu from qml in WebEngineView

Tags: qt, qml, qwebengineview

I'm programming a WebEngineView and I want to disable its context menu.
For what I already found I have to call QWidget's `setContexMenuPolicy`.
Unfortunately, all help in the Net I can find shows how to do it from C++ code, while I need to do it all from my `.qml` file (I have no access to the c++ code).

I tried `this.setContextMenuPolicy(...)` from `Component.onCompleted` signal inside the WebEngineView, but to no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found other way, which works for my case:

```
WebEngineView {
    anchors.fill: parent
    url: "https://www.example.com"
    onContextMenuRequested: {
        request.accepted = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't just access `QWidget` functions in QML if they aren't forwarded via `Q_PROPERTY`. You should read [The Property System](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/properties.html).

My solution is a bit of a hack. It's using a `MouseArea` which consumes right mouse clicks, basically blocks all right clicks on the `WebEngineView`:

**UPDATE!**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtWebEngine 1.0

Window {
    width: 1024
    height: 750
    visible: true
    WebEngineView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        url: "https://www.qt.io"
    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        acceptedButtons: Qt.LeftButton | Qt.MiddleButton | Qt.RightButton
        onPressed: {
            if (mouse.button === Qt.RightButton)
                mouse.accepted = true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I doesn't work with each cases: yes it blocks right button, but if you hold the left button over the View, it stills shows the menu. Even when I block all the buttons it still shows the menu :(

Comment: @Felix.leg I've updated my answer. The `MouseArea` now accepts all mouse buttons and checks in the `onPressed` if the `Qt.RightButton` was pressed. As far as I tested this should work. Any combination right, right + left, right + middle should be blocked and not open the context menu.